# Animation set. cant figure out how to make two animations with one image and one animationset

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I have rotate and translate animation in animation set. When user click on image that animationset start and it work good if its click once. When user click again and that animation is stoped and start new animation on the same image and the previous one is lost or its invisible. Can anyone help? thanks.
i wanna set that animation to be independently of one another if user click on image 3 times to start 3 animations. is that possible?
Here is my code:

```
RotateAnimation rAnim;
TranslateAnimation translateanim;

image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            while (true) {
                if ((count == 2)) {
                    StartAnim();
                    break;
                }

                if ((count == 1)) {
                    StartAnim();
                    break;
                }
        }

        }


    });
```

private void StartAnim() {

```
    animSet = new AnimationSet(true);

    rAnim = new RotateAnimation(-30.0F, 0.0F, 1, 0.5F, 1, 0.0F);
    rAnim.setDuration(50);

    rAnim.setInterpolator(new Interpolator() {
        public float getInterpolation(float v) {
            return 0.0F;
        }
    });
    rNum = new Random();
    rAnim.setDuration(50 + rNum.nextInt(150));
    rAnim.setRepeatCount((int) (1500 / rAnim.getDuration()));
    animSet.addAnimation(rAnim);
    translateanim = new TranslateAnimation(2,
            0.0F, 2, 0.1F + rNum.nextFloat() / 2.0F, 2, 0.0F, 2,
            1.0F + rNum.nextFloat());
    translateanim.setDuration(1500);
    animSet.addAnimation(translateanim);
    animSet.setFillAfter(true);


    image2.startAnimation(animSet);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if the user clicks on the image 3 times in a row you want it to animate 3 times? You could create an integer called animationCount. And then before calling metodaa() check if it is above 0 or not, if it is greater than 0, increment animationCount, otherwise start the animation. Then add a AnimationListener to your animSet so that on onAnimationEnd you decrement your animationCount and then if animationCount is greater than 0, start the animation again.

Comment: i want to have 3 animations like 3 new animations. if one animation starts thats okey but if user click again start new animation. but previous let finish.do you understand me ? and i tryed to add on metoddaa(); ImageView newImage = new ImageView(this); and them to add animset on that newImage. but didn't work.

Comment: Ok, so user clicks again to start a new animation while the previous one still continues. I would recommend using a canvas and animating your images as bitmaps on that. The Snake google sample app is a good example of animating multiple images and adding more in.

Comment: don't know much about canvas but i will try. thank you for helping me. i will try that sample.